# SSL CRL Expired Issue

Tags: ssl

SSLabs.com is reporting an issue with my SSL certificate.

I've never seen this error before. All 5 of my domains use Comodo SSL (separate certs) and are all showing this exact same error message.

Is there something that needs to be changed on my dedicated server? or is this an Comodo issue and I just have to wait it out?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Revocation status Good (not revoked)  
CRL ERROR: Processing failed: CRL expired [http://crl.comodoca.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crl]
```

Comment: It seems your certificate is ok: https://certificate.revocationcheck.com/crl.comodoca.com . Maybe the problem is with SSLabs.com . What do you think about?

Comment: SSLabs has been solid for years, I don't believe this issue is on their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRL expired means that the CRL provided by the CA has an "expiration" (actually "Next Update" field) in the past. It might be a temporally glitch by SSLLabs.com in that it got an old (cached) version of the CRL but it might also be a glitch in the operation of the CA in that it offered an expired CRL for download. Impossible to tell from the information provided. But at least the CRL currently offered for download on this URL is not expired yet.

Comment: Ok, so this is something that is out of my control then?

Comment: @BrianSmith: correct. You have no control over the CRL issued by the CA and how it gets processed by SSLLabs.

Comment: Ok great, I won't worry about it then and hopefully it gets sorted out soon.